# How to pass variable from child to parent at initial on Laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have parent blade link to child component as below.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{-- user crud component here --}}
        @livewire('components.employeecrud.employee-crud')
    </div>
```

And waiting event from child as below.

```
protected $listeners = [
    'dataToParent'
];

public function dataToParent($value)
{
    dd($value['user_ids']);
}
```

Then emit from child to parent on mount method.

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->emitUp('dataToParent',['user_ids'=>[1,2,3]]); 
}
```

Result return nothing that may cause of parent not finished load yet. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Livewire emits do **not** work before first render. This is because before then, the JavaScript isn't loaded in. There's a simple fix, however.

On the child component blade:

```html
<div wire:init="init()">
    {{-- Your component here --}}
</div>
```

In the component class:

```php
public function init() 
{
    $this->emitUp('dataToParent',['user_ids'=>[1,2,3]]); 
}
```

And then you're set!

A little explanation: `wire:init` is called when the component is first initialized. We then call a function by the name of "init", and basically have it do what we wanted to do what wasn't possible within the `mount` method.

Comment: Dear Yinci, thank for helping. btw, cool mime.